# Can you create an array with one position?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem. My code works when the JSON "Customers" comes as an array. **But when it has only 1 customer, my code creates 11 table columns** (amount of keys in the JSON).

**THE JSON comes from another app so I CANNOT CHANGE IT**

Code:

Getting the customers service.

```
// Get the customers
promises.customers.$promise.then(function (data) {
    if (data['Customer']) {
        vm.customers = data['Customer'].customers;
        console.log(vm.customers);
    }
});
```

Generating the HTML. **Like i said if it's an array it works great, but if it's only one customer it creates 11 columns instead of just one.**

```
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th ng-repeat="customer in vm.customers.Customers">Customer {{$index + 1}}</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

This JSON works:

```
{
  "Customers": [
   {
    "CUSTOMER_ID": "1",
    "FIRST_NAME": "Peter",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-21+00:00",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal",
    "_xmlns": ""
  },
  "CUSTOMER_ID": "2",
    "FIRST_NAME": "Bla bla",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-21+00:00",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal",
    "_xmlns": ""
  }
  ],
  "_xmlns": "http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/CMT/Customers"
}
```

This one doesn't

```
    {
  "Customers": {
    "CUSTOMER_ID": "1",
    "FIRST_NAME": "Peter",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-21+00:00",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal",
    "_xmlns": ""
  },
  "_xmlns": "http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/CMT/Customers"
}
```

Comment: `{  "Customers": [{` should be like this also in the second example, otherwise you're iterating on the object properties which, guess what, are 11.

Comment: Yeah I know that but it comes like this from another app. I dont know how but if I need to change, I need to do it in the function above.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the huge "**I CANNOT CHANGE IT**" signal

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it is an array and if not create one.

```
promises.customers.$promise.then(function (data) {
    if (data['Customer']) {
        vm.customers = data['Customer'].customers;

        // if not an array then assume that vm.customers is actually a single
        // instance in which case create a new array 
        // with that as the 1st element
        if(!Array.isArray(vm.customers)){
            vm.customers = [vm.customers];
        }

        console.log(vm.customers);
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try this. 2 minutes and I give feedback

Comment: hm... I still get the same JSON in the HTML.

Comment: @user9973778 - then either there is other code where the same (or similar) check needs to be added OR the change you made is not executing in your environment. You can test the latter by adding an additional `console.log` statement and possibly one inside the `if` block as well.

Comment: @user9973778 - if you manually copied over the change from my solution above make sure you included the `!` at the beginning of the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
promises.customers.$promise.then(function (data) {
    if (data['Customer']) {
        if( Array.isArray( data['Customer'].customers ) ) { 
            vm.customers = data['Customer'].customers;
            console.log(vm.customers);
        }else{
            vm.customers = [data['Customer'].customers];
            console.log(vm.customers);
        }
    }
});
```